# Nested attributes in hash representation of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-attributes

I've given up hours of my day trying to accomplish this simple thing in Rails 3.1 with no luck.  I've got some models nested 2 levels deep and associated many-to-one with belongs_to/foreign key, like:

```
TopLevelModel:
  MiddleLevelModel:
    BottomLevelModel
```

I am eagerly loading the whole hierarchy in my queries like so:

```
@model = TopLevelModel.find(1, :include => {:middle_level_children => :bottom_level_children})
```

The JSON serializer works fine for serializing the nested hierarchy (using the :include option), but this isn't enough for my purposes and I need a (ruby) hash representation of the record's attributes.  `@model.attributes()` would be perfect but it neglects my relations.  Is there a way to get a nested hash representation using this method (I read the documentation thoroughly and suspect not, but maybe there's some exotic option I don't know about).  To be clear, the representation I am looking for would be:

```
{ 
   :attribute_1 => 'some attribute', #an attribute of top level model
   #...
   :middle_level_children: => [{ # type 'MiddleLevelModel'
     :attr_1 => 'some attribute of middle level model',
     # ...
     :bottom_level_children => [{ #type 'BottomLevelModel'
        :attr => 'some attribute of bottom level model'
     }]
   }]
}
```

This seems like an incredibly simple (and, I would think, common) need, but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you iterate through all your child relationships and print all the `attributes` for each instance of them?

Comment: That's going to be my temporary solution, but I thought there was perhaps some more correct, automatic/reflective faculty for this.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little hokey but give Hash.from_xml a whirl.

Use the object's to_xml method to serialize with associations and then deserialize with the Hash.from_xml class method.

```
xml = @model_instance.to_xml(:include=>:middle_level_children)
nested_hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
```